# Getting cursor position in mailItem htmlbody

Tags: outlook, outlook-addin, mailitem

I am need to achieve the following behavior.
I have added some stuff to the mailItem.HTMLbody, a table with some data and a couple of links.

My plugin has a button, which when adds some html after the position of the cursor. This event may occure several times.

I have tried using WordDocument.selection class for this, but it works with the mailItem.body rather than the mailItem.HTMLBody.

How should I go about this?
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Outlook does not use an HTML editor on top of HTMLBody. It uses the Word editor accessible from `Inspector.WordEditor`.

Comment: Hello Dmitrii.
I'm afraid I don't see how your answer is relevant.

I am by no means an expert on outlook api, but I do believe my problem was clearly stated

Comment: What I am saying is that what you want is simply not there. Outlook used to have a pure HTML editor (2007 and older) accessible from Inspector.HTMLEditor), but the latest versions of Outlook (2010 and up) only use Word-lite accessible from Inspector.WordEditor. Nothing else is available. You will have to use the Word editor objects.